# Reading a MIDI file without going byte by byte

Tags: c#, .net, f#, midi

I need to read simple multi-track MIDI files using C#/F#. I began writing a binary reader, but it seems to be an overkill for this purpose. I tried several things I've found on Google, none worked (each with its own problem). The files are really simple (Bach's chorales - only chords, nothing fast, always 4 instruments).

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read MIDI file in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845825/how-to-read-midi-file-in-c)

Comment: What do you want to do? Play it?

Comment: @Hans: I read that one, didn't work for me. @Daniel: I need to store the notes in a data structure. @All: I found MuseScore which lets me convert MIDI to MusicXML, and MusicXML is trivial

Comment: MusicXML or DEC.exe which is described here: http://faydoc.tripod.com/formats/mid.htm is the way togo...probably.

Comment: @Alex, I think you are correct. For future readers: DEC.EXE isn't at the given site, but you can find the source code here: http://www.opennet.ru/docs/formats/midi.txt and compile it (with a C++ compiler).

Answer (score 2):

[NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com) can read and write MIDI files. I'm not sure what your problem was. Have a look at [MIDI file mapper](http://midifilemapper.codeplex.com) as an example of a project using NAudio to map drum beats.